# Why is the content of an HTML website in ISO-8859-1 format instead of UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, utf-8, character-encoding

I am creating a web application in Meteor where I scrape data from certain internet pages.

The doubt is simple, what happens is that when I extract the content of a web page. I have as a result the content HTML but in ISO-8859-1 format and not in UTF-8 as this web page is defined. As shown in the code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Judith Klavans - Citas de Google Académico</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
      <meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-cross-origin">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=2">
      <style>@viewport{width:device-width;min-zoom:1;max-zoom:2;}</style>
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon-png.ico">
      <link rel="canonical" href="http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=AxoaSbwAAAAJ&amp;hl=en">
```

Then, you can see the extract of the code where I make the request to the web page and I extract the data. I’m using a package called Cheerio, which is very usual for these cases.

```
Router.route('/scraper/:id_investigador', function() {
  this.response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  this.response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  this.response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, x-request-metadata');
  this.response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
  this.response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  var url = 'https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=' + id_investigador;

  request(url, async function(error, response, html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log(html);
  })
}, { where: "server" });
```

As you see in the code, the content of the page requested in the terminal is shown, but now it is in ISO-8859-1 format and not in UTF-8 format as seen in the first code. The problem is that the special characters do not see the content of the HTML, but are replaced by the symbol �.

For example: Google Académico (utf-8) -> Google Acad�mico (ISO-8859-1)

[image]

I wish that the HTML content of the requested web page could be obtained in the original format `utf-8` and thus be able to correct the special characters with the symbols �.

Comment: What do you use for `request`?

Comment: When UTF-8 would be shown as ISO-8859-1 then you should have two 'strange' characters instead of only one �. So the question is are you sure that your source is really UTF-8? I would like to suggest to verify with notepad++ for the case that you are on Wondows.